# C# Linq query with multiple where conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I want to grab members where status for all rows = 1 and also to make sure CreatedDate is today's date.

I grouped them but I dont know where do I need to place CreatedDate = Today

```
  var mids= _db.Members
             .GroupBy(m => new { m.MemberID, m.CreatedDate })
             .Where(m => m.All(s => s.Status == 1)) //&& m.CreatedDate.Value.ToShortDateString().Equals(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
             .Select(
                group => new
                {
                    MID = group.Key

                }).ToList();
```

I tried to add CreatedDate condition in the .Where clause but it gives me a compilation error.  How do I fix my syntax ? Merci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for today, you can more simply do

```
if(CreatedDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
```

then, you want to look at the keys:

```
var mids = _db.Members
         .GroupBy(m => new { m.MemberID, m.CreatedDate })
         .Where(m => m.All(s => s.Status == 1) && m.Key.CreatedDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
         .Select(
            group => new
            {
                MID = group.Key
            }).ToList();
```

or you can filter them before the GroupBy:

```
var mids = _db.Members
         .Where(m => m.CreatedDate.Date == DateTime.Today)
         .GroupBy(m => m.MemberID)
         .Where(m => m.All(s => s.Status == 1))
         .Select(
            group => new
            {
                MID = group.Key
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple syntax problem.  Remember that `m` is a [`IGrouping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb343251(v=vs.100).aspx)`<anonymous, memberType>` so your `.where` will need to use the `.Key` property to get to the actual anonymous object.

It looks like this

```
.Where(m => m.All(s => s.Status == 1) 

      &&  m.Key.CreatedDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
           .Equals(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work as welll:

```
var mids= _db.Members
       .Where(m=>m.Status==1 && m.CreatedDate==DateTime.Today)
       .Select(m=>m);
```